# How to see Google Analytics dimension variables on Dashboard

Tags: php, google-analytics

I am going through a strange problem; may be I am doing something wrong.

I need to see list of all Usernames (and their analytics) which logged in on my site. I created a dimension1 variable and listed as "User Name" with a "Session" type on Google Analytics.

### Here is what I did in my code:-

**P.S.** This code is in `analyticstracking.php` which is at the end of the page (after the "body" tag)

```
var user = "<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>";

  if (user) {
    //alert(user);
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'thesite.com');

    var dimensionValue = user;

    //ga('set', 'dimension1', dimensionValue); 
    ga('set', {
      'dimension1': dimensionValue,
      'metric1': 1
    }); 

    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

### This is what I did in Google Analytics:-

[image: GA Dimension]

Now I am hoping that after doing all this, I'd see the list of all recorded Usernames and when I click on them, It'd show me all the respective analytics.

But nothing is happening.

Any idea if I am doing something wrong?

Thanks

Comment: First off, it's against Google Analytics policy to send any Personally Identifiable Information (PII) into GA. You could send a User-id though. 

Second, did you create a custom report? You'll need to do that in order to view any custom dimension data.

Comment: Thank you Blexy, So I'd have to create a custom report for this? any idea how I can do that sir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, to create a custom report:

1. log into GA and go to "`Customization`" at the top, and then click "`+ New Custom Report`".
2. Select the metrics you want to see for the custom report e.g. sessions, pageviews, etc.
3. Select the dimension you want to see. In your case, that will be `User Name`.
4. Click save.

You should now see your data.

Again, I would strongly urge you to use User Id rather than User Name.

[image]