# How do I track userID across multiple form pages using Google Analytics Dimensions?

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I am trying to setup a simple dimensions tracker of userID numbers across multiple form pages.  I've seen so many variations of how to write the javascript code my head is spinning.

I understand the basic principles and how to setup the Custom Dimensions and the Report in GA.

For my purposes I found this stackflow question [How to see Google Analytics dimension variables on Dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274021/how-to-see-google-analytics-dimension-variables-on-dashboard) which is very close to what I want to accomplish. But I don't understand the difference between the many variations of writing this code.

In this line, what is the difference between 'auto' and inserting a domain name and when should you use each of these options?

`ga('create', 'UA-59928729-1', 'auto');`

In the stackflow question, what is the purpose of this line and is it necessary? 'metric1' is not reflected anywhere in the example's defined Custom Dimension or the Report:

`'metric1': 1`

Will it work if I just do this or am I missing a variable? (I left out the GA top function on purpose for simplicity).

```
    ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
    ga('set', 'dimension1', '<?php echo $userID; ?>');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Some articles include this.  Is it necessary? When would you use 'displayfeatures'?

`ga('require', 'displayfeatures');`

In the stackflow question, why is "Submitted Form" selected as a metric in the report instead of the variable name (in my case 'userID')?  There is no "Submitted Form" option in my Report page.

Finally, is there a reference somewhere that explains the different javascript options for 'set' and 'send' for writing this code?  How many variables can each of these take and what are the differences between them?  Maybe somebody needs to write an article on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cookie domain is set when you create your tracker object. It can be set with "auto" in which case the cookie domain is set to the highest domain level possible. By default, if you don't put anything in, GA will treat it as if you had put "auto" there (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains). "metric1" isn't something you need. If you don't know what it is, then you probably don't need it. "displayfeatures" is used for tracking demographics and interests data (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/display-features). Check this out for "send" and "set" definitions: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/domains.

Here is more info on implementing UserID: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-id

Generally speaking, you just need to do more research and Googling. All those links I found just by a simple search.